# Safari extension, open new tab with HTML page, pass parameters

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

In my extension I want to open a new tab when a toolbar button is clicked (works), display a static HTML page with JavaScript on the tab (works) and pass data (URL from the originating page) to the new tab (does not work). I tried:

- Using query parameters like `myTab.url = safari.extension.baseURI + 'page.html?' + params`, but the target page does not seem to have a location assigned (`location.search` giving no result).
- `myTab.page.dispatchMessage("url", "someUrl");` after opening the tab, but the message never arrives in the new tab (I suspect, it's already "through", when the tab has opened).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I parsed **document.URL** in opened page for specific parameter and it worked for me. E.g.

```
function __onLoad()
{
    var p = $.url(document.URL);
    alert(p.param("url"));
}
```

And two possible reasons for missed message:

- You did not add **message** event listener on your page
- You called **dispatchMessage** before event listener was added

Check Safari development doc at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is this ``$.url(document.URL);``? Is this Safari-specific or some library? I get a ``ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $``.

Comment: sorry, it was not clear. I used jQuery url parser plugin from https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser. But I just wanted to show that you may use regular expression or any other kind of tool to get your parameter from the document url

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late; I just verified it works simply by using ``document.URL``. Thank you!